# Garbage Collection of C++ externals

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I have made a game of connect-4 in C++ for some AI problem and connected it to a nodejs web server as an addon.

I works like this:

```
  v8::Isolate *isolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
  Game *game_ptr = new Game();
  game_ptr->nextPlayer();

  Local<ObjectTemplate> game_template = ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
  game_template->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
  Local<Object> game = game_template->NewInstance();
  game->SetInternalField(0, External::New(isolate, game_ptr));
```

My question is: Is the game (being used as a [`v8::External`](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-10.6/d8/d0f/classv8_1_1_external.html)) garbage collected or should I manage the memory myself?

And if I should manage the memory what are the best practices?

Comment: Make it a unique_pointer<Game> then it is. Otherwise call delete at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the mantra of `c++` only pay for what you use, there is no garbage collection. This means that you need to manage memory yourself. In this specific case you have 2 options:

1. Don't make game with `new`. Depending on your application, just using `Game game;` may be enough.
2. If you really need to `new` `Game`, wrap the new in an RAII (Resource acquisition is initialization) idiom type. You can leverage `c++` smart pointers:

   `auto game_ptr = std::make_unique<Game>();`

   When the scope of the [`unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) ends, the memory that it contains will be automatically released.

Comment: (This question is in the context of Node.js, which is a GC'ed environment. Nonetheless, v8 doesn't free memory wrapped in `External`s.)